# Wordpress MU 2.9.2 to 3.0.5 changes to category.php

Tags: categories, upgrade, multisite

In the latest version of WP I see the category.php page is now using edit-tags.php.
The version Im running seems to have an issue with the search feature on this page whereas the new version doesnt. When searching for categories, the results show the category search AND its heirarchy i.e. - categoryname together in the same list. Short of doing a major overhaul and upgrade as one does need to check compatibility, what was changed in the new version that I could update in the old version of my source?

example: I have 5 categorys, 3 parents, 2 children. They all have the word cat in their name. If I search for the word 'cat' I not only get the 5 results, but ALSO another three results with - category name for each of the children again. This is not the case in 3.0.5

Comment: You'll have to paste some code before we could even begin to guess what the problem is. Does your theme have code that alters the old category.php in admin in any way?

Comment: No this is default WPMU 2.9.2 and 3.0.5. The new version does have some significant differences in the wp-admin/includes/template.php file from what I can see.

Comment: another thing Ive notice with the search box itself on either version is that its not urlencoded i.e. try searching from an category with an & its name and then search for the same category but encode it yourself i.e. 'category &amp; name' - this works but reverts the 's' to the &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you on the WPMU -> 3x transition but unfortunately it's going to be hard to troubleshoot the issues without seeing any code (@sanchothefat says something similar in a comment above). I've come up against similiar issues, so let me at least offer some general help in debugging these kinds of things.

Whatever the function in question, go into the SVN and compare code revisions for the function in question. [Here's the WPMU 2.9.2 trunk](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-mu/tags/2.9.2/) and here's [3.0.5](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/tags/3.0.5/).

Try using a diff tool ("diff file1 file2" on the command line) and see what changed between revisions. Are all the parameters the same? Do those array keys exist in both versions?

To slueth out what your code isn't doing anymore it's helpful to first figure out it *did* do that is no longer.

Comment: looking at the depreciated function list is also most useful...